# How to load not active customers in magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

I need to load only inactive customers from magento collection.

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addNameToSelect()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('email')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('created_at')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('group_id')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('confirmation') 
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*');`

  $collection 
    ->joinAttribute('billing_postcode', 'customer_address/postcode', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
    ->joinAttribute('billing_city', 'customer_address/city', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
    ->joinAttribute('billing_telephone', 'customer_address/telephone', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
    ->joinAttribute('billing_region', 'customer_address/region', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
    ->joinAttribute('billing_country_id', 'customer_address/country_id', 'default_billing', null, 'left');
```

And from this collection i tried to add

```
$collection->getSelect()->where("e.is_active = 0 ");
```

But it throws exception and am not able to load only inactive customers inside admin custom module. Please help  me on loading inactive customers.

Note:
From front-end by default i setup all the customers registration as "is_active" to be 0 , so after admin approval only customers will be active. For that i need to load all those inactive customers.

Comment: It maybe: `$collection->getSelect()->where("maintable.is_active = 0 ")`

Answer (score 0):

Try `$collection->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 0)`

Answer (score -1):

According to [this magento thread](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/43600/) there could be a bug in definition of default attributes of Customer Entity. Try to look into `Mage_Customer_Model_Entity_Customer`, in this method:

```
protected function _getDefaultAttributes()
{
    return array(
        'entity_type_id',
        'attribute_set_id',
        'created_at',
        'updated_at',
        'increment_id',
        'store_id',
        'website_id'
    );
}
```

there should be:

```
protected function _getDefaultAttributes()
{
    return array(
        'entity_type_id',
        'attribute_set_id',
        'created_at',
        'updated_at',
        'increment_id',
        'store_id',
        'website_id',
        'is_active'
    );
}
```

If this is the case then [Zyava's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7542047/how-to-load-not-active-customers-in-magento/7861740#7861740) neither this one: `$collection->addFieldToFilter('is_active', 0)`
won't probably work.